# Can't validate prop in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to check if drop down from the list of dropdown is on the bottom of the screen then drop down items should be opened on the top otherwise it should be opened on the bottom. Data is getting received from the parent page. Here is how code looks like:

```
 <div class="level-right" ref=isBottom>
        <b-dropdown
        v-if="dropdownItems.length"
          aria-role="list"
          position="is-bottom-left"
        >
          <b-button
            slot="trigger"
            icon-right="ellipsis-h"
          >
          </b-button>

          <b-dropdownItem
            aria-role="listitem"
            v-for="item in dropdownItems"
            :key="item.id"
          >
            {{ item.name }}
          </b-dropdownItem>
        </b-dropdown>
      </div> 

props: {
    dropdownItems: Array,
  },

isDropdownInBottom(){
        if(this.dropdownItems.length){
       let elementHeight = this.$refs.isBottom.clientHeight * this.dropdownItems.length
      let bottomSpace = window.innerHeight - this.$refs.isBottom.offsetTop + elementHeight
     if (elementHeight >= bottomSpace) {
       return "is-top-left"
     }
     else {
       return
         "is-bottom-left"
       }
     }
     }
```

I need to change this in drop down:

```
 position="is-bottom-left"
```

From parent it receives this data:

```
  dropdownItems: {
    view: {
      name: 'View',
      ...
    },
    edit: {
      name: 'Edit',
      ....
    },
    delete: {
      name: 'Delete'
     ...

    },
  },
```

Based on the above function return but whatever I do it either shows prop validation is failed or it shows that elementHeight, dropdownItems.length or offsetTop are undefined. Data is getting received from parent page so that's why I have added if conditions but it still doesn't accept that return value from the function into that position prop. I have placed there static option now for hiding error. How can this result be achieved correctly?

Comment: could you please edit the question with the parent page?

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I've updated code. There is no any problem with binding. Data is displaying fine problem is that above function based on which it should decide to change the position prop of the drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're passing an object and trying to accept it as an array so it is failing. Try this

```
  dropdownItems:[
 {
  name: 'View',
 },
 {
  name: 'Edit',
 },
 {
  name: 'Delete'
 },
]
```

You could bind the position this way in your dropdown this way

```
 :position="position"
```

And in your data, you have it this way

```
data(){
  return {
    position: "is-bottom-left",
  }
}
```

In your, if statement return it this way

```
this.position = "is-top-left"
```

In your else

```
return this.position
```

Comment: Still not working. The problem is related to the function isDropdownInBottom  and the binding of position prop

Comment: @NewTechLover please check my updated answer if it helps you out.

Comment: It shows prop: custom validator check failed for prop "position". Also length is undefined for that function

Comment: Also offsetHeight, clientHeight both are showing undefined

Comment: could you create a  fiddle or a codepen so I can replicate the project at my end? it seems there are lots of things going on which is not part of the question.

Comment: Thanks it fixed. Can you please check this as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911755/bottom-distance-of-the-nested-item-and-the-window-always-returns-the-same-while

It's related to this question.